# Accessing child object from parent object in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've searched the whole net, but still I can't get this to work.

What I need is a simple list that looks like this:

- **ParentName1**
- ChildName1
- ChildName2
- **ParentName2**
- ChildName3

I have one table of the Parent objects and one of the Child objects. In the table of Child objects, there is a foreign key ParentId.

Now, I use strongly typed ViewModel and Intellisense even suggests the Child properties through a Parent.Child.Property, but then when I run the program I get a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

*My Parent class looks like this:*

```
    public class EmployeeArea
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int? StudioCode { get; set; }

        public string AreaName { get; set; }

        public List<EmployeeName> EmployeeNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*And my Child class looks like this:*

```
    public class EmployeeName
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int AreaId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Do I need to do something in the DbContext ModelBuilder? I welcome any help. Thank you!

Comment: What's your query look like to pull the data from the database?  Also I don't see any attributes setting up the foreign key relationship here.

Comment: I use EF Core, so I just created the classes and added them as a DbSet. It all works well, but only when I don't need anything referenced by a foreign key. The Entity Framework should also make a shadow FK attribute on it's own. At least that's what the documentation states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can't see your query but I'd suggest the following.
First, the foreign key should be :

```
public int EmployeeAreaId {get; set;}
```

then you have two options to get data from database.
If you are using EF, then:

```
db.EmployeeArea.Include(e => e.EmployeeName).ToList();
```

which will return a list of employeeArea including the child list.

Using Linq will be like :

```
var employeeArea = (from e in db.EmployeeArea
                    select new EmployeeArea
                               {
                                  Id = e.Id
                                  // continue populating the model properties
                                  EmployeeNames = db.EmployeeName.Where(e => 
                                  e.EmployeeAreaId == e.Id).ToList(),
                               }).ToList()
```

Excuse any typo here. Hope it helps.

Be sure when looping through parents to check if their child list is **null**.

Comment: OK, so I will need to make a query in the controller, pass it into my Viewmodel and then use it in a view. How can I then filter the children by the parent? When I list the children i just use (foreach var employeeName in model.NameModel), and for listing the parents I use (foreach var employeeArea in model.AreaModel). But I don't know how to get children grouped by the parent. Damn I might just be too stupid. I've been working with EF and ASP Core for a few months, but I just can't get my head around this.

Comment: It's a simple one, when looping through parents, foreach(var employee in EmployeeArea) {// do something with children, like: foreach(var employeeName in employee.EmployeeName) { // Here you get all the children of that parent }}

Comment: I put a breakpoint there and the List<EmployeeName> EmployeeNames is null for each parent Area. The children are just not getting referenced. I'll comment here if I get anything useful.

Comment: be sure to name things correct, like the foreign key should be like the first line in my answer, otherwise, EF will not be able to read it as a foreign key.

Comment: You were right about the naming! Now it works, but when there is a parent area with no children it throws an error that there is a reference to null object. But the main issue is solved thanks to you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first define the foreign key properly by overriding OnModelCreating or by convention:

```
public int EmployeeAreaId {get; set;}
```

If you are using strongly typed ViewModels you need to use EFCore Projections(https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-projection), the code would look something like this(replace with your viewmodel names):

```
db.EmployeeAreas.Select(e => new YourViewModel{
  ParentName = e.AreaName,
  ChildNames = e.EmployeeNames.Select(en => new List<string>{
    EmployeeName = en.Name
  }).ToList();
}).ToList();
```

If this were Json it would look like this:

```
[
  {
    ParentName : "ParentName1",
    ChildNames ; ["ChildName1","ChildName2"]
  },
  {
    ParentName : "ParentName2",
    ChildNames ; ["ChildName3"]
  }
]
```